# How do I subtract/divide with arrays

Tags: java

```
//Declare and intialize variables - programmer to provide initial values
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String city = "Daytona Beach";
    String state = "Florida";
    double a =0;

    String month [] ={"Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    double temperature [] = {58.4, 60.0, 64.7, 68.9,74.8, 79.7, 81.7, 81.5,79.9,74.0,67.0,60.8};        
    double precipitation [] ={3.1, 2.7,3.8,2.5,3.3,5.7,5.2,6.1,6.6,4.5,3.0,2.7};    
    String tempLabel = "F";   //initialize to F
    String precipLabel = "inch"; //initialize to inch

    double c [] = {32.0};
    double q [] = {0.5555};

    //INPUT - ask user for temp and preciptation scale choice
    System.out.print("Choose the temperature scale (F = Fahrenheit, C = Celsius): ");
    String tempChoice = in.next();
    System.out.print("Choose the precipitation scale (i = inches, c = centimeteres): ");
    String precipChoice = in.next();


    //PROCESSING - convert from F to C and in to cm based on user's choices

    // remember 5/9 = 0, 5.0/9 = .5555

    if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
    {
        tempLabel="(C)";


        for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)
        {

        }

    }

    //Convert in values to cm; replace the current values in precipitation
    if(precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
    {
        precipLabel="(cm)";


    }

    //OUTPUT - print table using printf to format and align data

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Climate Data");
    System.out.println("Location: " + city +", " + state);
    System.out.printf("%5s %18s %s %18s %s","Month","Temperature",tempLabel,"Precipitation",precipLabel);
    System.out.printf("***************************************************");
    System.out.printf("%s\n",month);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("***************************************************");
    System.out.println();
```

Don't worry about converting the precipitation. How do I convert the multiple array values (which are in fahrenheit)?  I tried doing (exmple) : a[i] = b[i]-c[i] but always get the error to close up the temperature array. The error was " ']' was expected.

** I also get the compiler warning of " Warning from last compilation:

- non-varargs call varargs with inexact argument type for a last
  perimeter;
- cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
- cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress the
  warning

Comment: please post the specific error message

Comment: Please show the actual code you tried to use as well as the **full** error message. Don't paraphrase as your question is now missing important information (that you probably don't realize is important).

Comment: @vandale: make that an answer, please.

Comment: What are you trying to divide and by what? You can divide objects in arrays like you would normally e.g anArray[3] /= 5;

Comment: Added two more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it as simple as possible.

```
for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++) {
    double celsius = (temperature[i] - 32)*5/9;
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels temperature[i] is already a `double` and so the calculation always involves a double.

Answer (score 2):

If the `a` you are referring to in your example is the `double a` you declared then it's because `a` is not an array.

Also c and q should most likely be plain `double`s and not arrays

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
{
    tempLabel="(C)";


    for( int index = 0; index < temperature.length; index++)
    {
        temperatue = (temperature[index] - 32)*5/9;
        temperature[index] = temperatue;
    }

}
```